# Android Java USB for native cpp

Tags: java, android, c++, usb

Is there a possibility to do similar Android Java code inside native CPP?

```
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint;

        UsbManager m = (UsbManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(USB_SERVICE);
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> usbDevices = m.getDeviceList();


        Collection<UsbDevice> ite = usbDevices.values();
        UsbDevice[] usbs = ite.toArray(new UsbDevice[]{});
        if(usbs.length == 0) {
            Log.d("Mainactivity","Drives empty");
        }
        for (UsbDevice usb : usbs) {

            UsbInterface intf = usb.getInterface(0);

            //UsbEndpoint endpoint1 = intf.getEndpoint(0);
            //UsbEndpoint endpoint2 = intf.getEndpoint(1);



        }
```

Maybe a headerfile or lib?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The [Android NDK overview](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference) does not mention USB. You will have to use equivalent JNI code to get the same results.